# using a if statement in a generic detail view

Tags: django, django-views

I am having trouble to figure out how to manage my error:

my app is built that way :

1. a user create a project
2. the user is redirected to a project
   detail page
3. The user is asked to create a team and add members to that project
4. The user is again redirected to the project detail page rendering now the team name and a list of all the team members.

My problem is that I wanted to add a context_data to render in my HTML

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(ProjectDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    team_name = Project.objects.get(id=self.kwargs['pk']).team_id.members.all()
    context['team_name'] = team_name
    return context
```

but now when I create a project since there is no team and member yet, I am getting an error 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'members'

How can I do? is there a way to add a if statement in a view ?

Comment: Can you add your models?

Comment: Also what view do you have a problem with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use if statement in this case. Just check that object has team_id:

```
obj = Project.objects.get(id=self.kwargs['pk'])
if obj.team_id:
    team_name = obj.team_id.members.all()
    context['team_name'] = team_name
return context
```

But also you can catch `AttributeError` with `try except` syntax like this:

```
try:
   team_name = Project.objects.get(id=self.kwargs['pk']).team_id.members.all()
   context['team_name'] = team_name
except AttributeError:
    pass
return context
```